# How do I visualize a time and space sequence of events in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, spatial-statistics, visualisation, time

I would like to visualize this scenario:

I have 5 weather stations. I would like to present a sequence of rainfall events for them. For example, rain was starts at station 2 at 6:09 and then went to station 5 after 8 minutes and ...

Please guide me on how I can visualize the aforementioned scenario as a snap shot via GIS.

Suggestions with tools description are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to symbolize the stations in graduated colours (light to dark for early to late time) or graduated symbols (small to large for early to late time), with or without labels of the times beside each, essentially using your time field to [represent quantity](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=About_symbolizing_data_to_represent_quantity). See [Drawing features to show quantities](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Drawing_features_to_show_quantities). Depending on the number of stations this may become confusing, so see below.

This may sound unconventional, but perhaps try the [GPS Toolbar](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Getting_started_with_ArcMap_GPS_Support) using your stations as simulated GPS connection. See [page 3 from this instruction guide](http://www.biology.ualberta.ca/gis/uploads/instructions/AVVisualizeMovement.pdf) on symbolizing and settings. Use Ctrl-PrtScr on the keyboard to capture screenshots at any point during the simulation, and then paste this into your graphics program or document file.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for might be implemented via [Animation tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_time_animation/000900000067000000/) as well as the [Time Slider](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_the_Time_Slider_window/005z0000000z000000/):

```
The Time Slider  window provides controls that allow you to visualize temporal data in ArcGIS.
```

Comment: What I need is a snap shot and using visualization elements such as color and symbols, while I want to put it in hard-copy document.